# OpenCV Cascade Classifier accuracy on MIT CBCL dataset

Tags: opencv, cascade-classifier

I want to find the accuracy of running OpenCV's [Cascade Classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html)'s on [MIT CBCL Face database](http://cbcl.mit.edu/software-datasets/FaceData2.html). Specifically, I want to find the accuracy of [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml) and [this XML](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml).

When I run the following code, no face is detected on the MIT dataset:

```
total_faces=0
for each_image in dirs:
   img = cv2.imread(base_path+"/"+each_image)
   img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img)
   total_faces += len(faces)
```

I have even tried to rescale the image using `img = cv2.resize(img, (20, 20))` as the window-size in the XML is 20*20 but to no avail.

Please suggest what be done. Thanks!